# Filter tab-completion per application by extension

Tags: command-line, zsh, auto-completion

Say `someprogram` needs only `*.abc` files as command line arguments. In terminal, when I do

```
$ someprogram <tab>
```

I'd like to only the `*.abc` files to be listed for tab auto-complete. How do I do that? The shell I use is `zsh`.

In `bash` this behaviour is achieved by `complete -f -X '!*.abc' someprogram`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List only `*.abc` files:

```
compctl -g '*.abc' someprogram
```

List folders, too:

```
compctl -/ -g '*.abc' someprogram
```

Comment: Great. It does the trick.